# How to get data from Junction Table using DB First Approach in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, many-to-many, db-first

I have Many to many Relationship between 2 tables and i want to retrieve data from junction table.

I'm sharing some source first

Image of Database tables:

https://imgur.com/BDvPiQa

Image of EF Model Entities:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qHOO.jpg

Image of error when debug:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIIJS.jpg

I am using following rules or strategies

+Database First Approach

+EF Diagram

+Custom Role Provider

Problem is that while I'm trying to retrieve data from Junction Table (user_has_role), I am getting SQL Query rather than Data.###

SQL Query which I get:

> SELECT \r\n    [Extent1].[user_id] AS [user_id], \r\n    [Extent2].[user_role_name] AS [user_role_name]\r\n    FROM  [dbo].[user_has_role] AS [Extent1]\r\n    INNER JOIN [dbo].[user_role] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[user_role_id] = [Extent2].[user_role_id]

Here is some code

Role Provider Class is Derived From RoleProvider Class

```
public class AppRolesProvider : RoleProvider
```

All methods are override but working with only

```
public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
        {
            //get all user data from user table for id based on user email
            var _user = db.users.Where(u => u.user_email == username).FirstOrDefault();

           var _role = (from s in db.users
                         where (
                           from c in s.user_role
                           where s.user_id == _user.user_id
                           select c
                           ).Any()
                         select s).ToString();

            string[] roleName = { _role };   

            if (roleName != null)
            {
                return roleName;
            }
            else
            {
                roleName = null;
                return roleName;
            }
        }
```

I want actual roleName against user (one user have many roles or maybe one)

### Updated

[Updated db image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWsNs.png)

and try to retrieve data from junction table but getting this query

> "SELECT \r\n    [Extent1].[user_id] AS [user_id], \r\n    [Extent2].[user_role_name] AS [user_role_name]\r\n    FROM  [dbo].[user_has_role] AS [Extent1]\r\n    INNER JOIN [dbo].[user_role] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[user_role_id] = [Extent2].[user_role_id]\r\n    WHERE [Extent1].[user_id] = @p__linq__0"

not data

Here is my method to get role in string array

```
public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
    {
        //get all user data from user table for id based on user email
        int _user_id = Convert.ToInt32(db.users.Where(u => u.user_email == username).Select(i => i.user_id).FirstOrDefault());

        // Get role from user_has_role against user id
        var _roles = (from _uhr in db.user_has_role
                      join _r in db.user_role on _uhr.user_role_id equals _r.user_role_id
                      where _uhr.user_id == _user_id
                      select new
                      {
                          _r.user_role_name
                      }).ToString();

        // store selected
        string[] roleName = { _roles };  

        if (roleName != null)
        {
            return roleName;
        }
        else
        {
            roleName = null;
            return roleName;
        }
    }
```

[output image in debug mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znrkF.png)

### Updated

[EDMX Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhYUr.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The junction table was not included by Entity Framework because it did not have a primary key. you fix this problem by adding a primary key to the junction table then update your Edmx file.

After updating model, you can retrieve data from your junction table with a simple linq query.

The difference between the two cases:

1) if your junction table doesn't contain a primary key, EF will generate two class with many to many relation
2) if your junction table contain a primary key, EF will generate 3 Class with: Junction table in one to many relation with user and one to many with user_role

### Update

Try with this please :

```
public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
    {
        //get all user data from user table for id based on user email
        int _user_id = Convert.ToInt32(db.users.Where(u => u.user_email == username).Select(i => i.user_id).FirstOrDefault());

        // Get role from user_has_role against user id
        var _role = db.user_has_role.Where(r => r.user_id == _user_id).Select(r => r.user_role.user_role_name);

        // store selected
        string[] roleName = _role.ToArray();

        if (roleName != null)
        {
            return roleName;
        }
        else
        {
            roleName = null;
            return roleName;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I know that but if i dont want to add primary key so what can i do for getting data?

Comment: @alaaeddin-hfidhi i m try to to do like u asked me to add primary key in junction table,
but i m not getting my output
i have updated my question please look at thi and help me out

Comment: @alaaeddin-hfidhi i want roleName in string array

Comment: can you send me a screenshot of your EDMX file ?

Comment: U know the solution?

Comment: it took so long time i m stuck please help me

Comment: I updated my answer !! if this solution still not working tell me please

Comment: thank you so much for helping me.
i have updated ur given solution a bit and resolve my issue thanx again bro

Comment: For me Linq with method syntax is better than linq with query syntax , it render code more clean.

Comment: yup u r right.
thank you so much again for help me bro